# Why does `ls` without any arguments (only flags) give me "no such file or directory"?

Tags: linux, unix, ls

When I pass `--color=always` to ls, it occasionally outputs a number of `No such file or directory` errors, like this:

```
~/svn/projects/submm/adda/scat$ /bin/ls --color=always
ls: cannot access adda_output_f89: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access adda_output_f150: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access adda_output_f183: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access adda_output_f186: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access adda_output_f190: No such file or directory
...
```

Later follow the contents of the directory, *including* the subdirectory `adda_output_f89` coloured as a directory.

There is a process running that is operating on files in this directory, but I don't think it's doing anything with the directories that `ls` is mentioning.

It is not fully reproducible. I have so far not succeeded in finding out a pattern when it happens and when it doesn't happen. It appears to happen in waves. Perhaps a process is rapidly creating and removing directories, but I don't think that's true.

It appears to be happening only when I pass `--color=always`, but I am not 100% sure that this is the case. Normally I use an alias, `ls='ls --classify --color=always --human-readable'` where it does happen, but when I call `/bin/ls` it appears that it does not happen.

**Edit**:

`ls -i` gives for those files:

```
? adda_output1_f243/  ? adda_output_f243/
```

etc.

**Edit**:

This is a nfs filesystem.

What might cause this behaviour? Is it some kind of race condition?

Comment: Are you sure the error only occurs when using `--color=always`? Also, are you sure you always use`/bin/ls` and not an alias?

Comment: Normally I use `ls`, which is for me an alias for `ls --classify --color=always --human-readable`. It does not happen when I use a pure `/bin/ls` or `/bin/ls --classify`. I did not try all combinations of options.

Comment: What happens with `"ls" --color=always`?

Comment: @speakr Unfortunately I haven't yet been able to find a way to reliably reproduce the issue, and right now it's not happening at all... I'll update if the problem returns.

Comment: I think you found the answer, "Perhaps a process is rapidly creating and removing directories" I can't really imagine another reason.

Comment: @terdon Right, but why would that cause the observed problem? Does `ls` go through the contents of a directory twice?

Comment: @gerrit: It finds the dir name using some kind of a `readdir`. It then tries to `stat` the dir to get the details, but the directory suddenly does not exist.

Comment: @choroba Right. How can I test that this is indeed the case? Note my edit; it doesn't report any inode for those directories either, but it does recognise that they are directories (with `-F`).

Comment: It could also be filesystem corruption -- dirent table corrupted or so. Run your filesystem's `fsck` tool in read-only mode to see if the volume is in a consistent state.

Comment: @allquixotic I'll ask my sysop tomorrow. Your comments remind me of a possibly relevant fact: it's NFS.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, `ls` in an NFS mount will result in two separate NFS calls, with a slight delay between them. If you suspect some process might be adding and removing entries in the directory I would definitely pursue that as an explanation. Here is how I would test that theory.

If the problem occurs some significant number of times you run `ls` (i.e., it would be easy to reproduce by manually running `ls` multiple times) you could simply:

```
{ ls;ls;ls; } 2>&1 | tee ls.out | grep 'No such file'
```

Re-run that command until you get the error, then inspect the `ls.out` file, find which files it was complaining about, then see if those files 1) exist in the first 1/3 of the output and 2) don't exist in the last 1/3 of the output. Since the files were (presumably) deleted while one of the `ls` commands was being run it shouldn't be too hard to figure out if they were there before and removed after.

If reproduction is significantly time-consuming you could write a script along the lines of (untested!):

```
#!/bin/bash

while /bin/true; do
  /bin/ls -lc >ls1.out 2>&1
  /bin/ls -lc >ls2.out 2>&1
  /bin/ls -lc >ls3.out 2>&1
  grep 'No such file' ls2.out >missing.out 2>&1
  if (( $? != 0 )); then
    echo "Found the error!"
    break
  fi
done
```

(Add `sleep`s if you're worried about the performance impact of running this in an unbridled tight loop.)

Run this in a `screen` session and check on it later. When the script exits reporting that it found the error, check `missing.out` to see which files `ls` couldn't find, then verify whether those files are listed in `ls1.out` but not `ls3.out`.

Don't forget to verify the ctime reported by `ls`, in case this mystery process happens to delete the file, then recreate a new file with the same name just in time for the third `ls` to list it. :)

If it turns out that for some reason the cause *isn't* that the process had deleted the file while `ls` was running, report back here and we'll figure out what else to try.